# How to make android navigation drawer scroll-able with header Scroll

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I want to make a custom navigation drawer where i want that it will be scroll-able .

[image]

Here is  my layout . I have tried it at different way . 
But its scroll only the list items not header .So how can i make it whole navigation drawer( include header )  scroll-able.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"

    tools:context="com.ajkerdeal.app.Fragments.HomeCategoryFragment"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_background3"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


        <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView

            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_portrait"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:text="Ehsanul Hauque"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ehsan@gmail.com" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView


        android:background="#D8D8D8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="20dp"

        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="হোম"
        android:textStyle="bold"



        android:id="@+id/textView2"
         />




    <LinearLayout

        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:paddingTop="178dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">




        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view_from_homecategoryfragment"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:onClick="viewClick"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />


    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set `ScrollView` as root view and put your `RelativeLayout` inside it

Comment: https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your whole content inside a `scrollview`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        tools:context="com.ajkerdeal.app.Fragments.HomeCategoryFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/splash_background3"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_portrait"
                app:border="true"
                app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
                app:border_width="4dp"
                app:shadow="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                android:text="Ehsanul Hauque"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ehsan@gmail.com"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#D8D8D8"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="হোম"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="178dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view_from_homecategoryfragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="viewClick"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: but when i put scroll such way then list of json data are hiding . whole layout  changed .

Comment: did u tried to build it and run on an emulator or real device.?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options you can go for to make the navigation drawer scrollable.

1.You can put everything inside a ScrollView so that the whole page will start scrolling based on the device size.So just use ScrollView as the root layout.I am posting a demo code below.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/login_bg"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/login_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="35dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
```

2.Or you can use a ListView or a RecyclerView based on your requirement to make the content part scroll.

But as you want the whole page to scroll including the Header part,I would suggest you to follow the first option.Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your NavigationView XML file

```
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true";
```